# Book about a boy who goes to a "school" and learns about dragons

Tags: story-identification, books, dragons

There's this one book I found years ago when I was a kid. The main plot revolves about a boy being so sent to a relative, who turns out to be teaching kids near his age about dragons. I don't know if I ever read it fully, but I do remember several footnotes so hopefully this will be enough:

- The book has a prologue, and there's a dragon egg mentioned.
- Dragons are a secret in this world; only this society knows about them. The boys parents know about dragons and they send him to this relative because they are going on a trip to find more dragons, if I recall correctly.
- The boy finds out that dragons are real because his relative keeps a baby dragon in his barn (?). I think the the first time he sees the dragon, he gets injured. And I remember the dragon having black eyes, but that might be bogus.
- I don't know what happens in-between, but the end of book involves an evil man going to a cathedral of some sort where a grown dragon is (this one can speak) and wounding her with a spear. I don't remember if she dies, but I remember the characters having to go down a hole with a rope.

And yeah that's all I remember; hopefully one of you will recognise this. Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you recall anything about the cover?

Comment: I think I read it between 2011 and 2014. Not sure about the release date at all. For the cover the only thing I distinctly remember is that it was red except for the cover art which was black and white.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Dragons-Ordinary-Farm-Tad-Williams/dp/0061543454 is probably too YA?

Comment: No there weren't any other magical creatures involved, only dragons.